# Replacing variables in string from AWS globals

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am writing a sample app for CDK and writing some SSM values but want to replace the current region in the string value written based on global variables (e.g. {{global:REGION}} in the string.  when synth / deploying a project, how do I lever environment / global context values in an existing string so that it writes the value into the string when pushing the values into AWS?

e.g.

```
ssmParamterValue = 'I am working in region {{global:REGION}} which should be written'
```

I would expect the value above when written to SSM would be:
'I am working in region us-east-1 which should be written'

I have other environment values I am setting as well, but this is one of the globals available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the AWS recommendation to [explicitly define env at synth-time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html)<sup>*</sup>, you can reference the env string values using the [Stack construct properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html) (e.g. `Stack.region` and `Stack.account`).

```js
// MyStack.ts
const ssmParamterValue = `I am working in region ${this.region} which should be written`
```

---

* If you are instead using environment-agnostic stacks, these values will be [tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/tokens.html) at synth-time and resolved to strings at deploy-time.  CDK is usually smart enough to convert typescript interpolated strings to the CloudFormation `Join` equivalent.